# Program hangs when implementing linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

The goal of this program is to gain  a better understanding of linked lists. I am supposed to create the function PromoteTarget that does the following:

- Goes through a list of numbers and if the number specified isn't found (target) then it is appended to the end of the list. If the list is empty, then target becomes the head.
- If target is found in the list one or more times, then the target numbers are to be brought to the front of the list. I should be able to do this without changing or deleting any nodes.

Here is my code:

```
      void PromoteTarget(Node*& headPtr, int target)
    {

    Node *current = headPtr;
    Node *prevnode = headPtr;
    int count = 0;
    while (current != 0) {
        if (current->data == target) {
            count++;
        }
        current = current->link;
    }
    if (count == 0) {

        Node *newNodePtr = new Node;
        newNodePtr->data = target;
        newNodePtr->link = 0;
        if (headPtr == 0)
            headPtr = newNodePtr;
        else
        {
            Node *cursor = headPtr;

            while (cursor->link != 0)
                cursor = cursor->link;
            cursor->link = newNodePtr;
        }
    }

    if (count > 0) {
        current = headPtr;
        while (current != 0) {
            if (current->data == target) {
                prevnode->link = current->link;
                current->link = headPtr;
                headPtr = current;
            }
            prevnode = current;
            current = current->link;
        }
    }
    }
```

This is an example of what I should receive as output:

```
================================
passed test on empty list
================================
initial: 4  5  
(target: 3)
ought2b: 4  5  3  
outcome: 4  5  3  
================================
initial: 3  4  5  7  4  5  
(target: 5)
ought2b: 5  5  3  4  7  4  
outcome: 5  5  3  4  7  4  
================================
initial: 7  6  4  3  4  5  
(target: 4)
ought2b: 4  4  7  6  3  5  
outcome: 4  4  7  6  3  5  
================================
initial: 6  5  7  5  3  5  6  5  3  
(target: 7)
ought2b: 7  6  5  5  3  5  6  5  3  
outcome: 7  6  5  5  3  5  6  5  3  
================================
initial: 5  
(target: 6)
ought2b: 5  6  
outcome: 5  6  
================================
initial: 5  6  4  4  5  7  
(target: 6)
ought2b: 6  5  4  4  5  7  
outcome: 6  5  4  4  5  7  
================================
```

This is what I am actually getting:

```
================================
passed test on empty list
================================
initial: 4  5  
(target: 3)
ought2b: 4  5  3  
outcome: 4  5  3
```

The program hangs and never gives me the full output. Based on the output I am getting though, I have a pretty good feeling about the first half of my program working as intended. Although I could totally be wrong.
If I had to guess, my problem occurs whenever I try to move the elements to the front of the linked list. Does my logic look ok? Am I forgetting or missing something or did I just make a dumb mistake?

Comment: When your program hangs, break it with a debugger. What line does it say it's on?

Comment: The code as presented creates no output, making it rather difficult for us to debug based on your stated symptom. I'd advise you to [debug your small program](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), narrow down where the problem occurs, and create a [mcve] based upon what you learned from debugging.

Comment: One possibility would be that you have an infinite loop (circular list) but we cannot know since we have no idea how you build the list. Either by using a debugger or add some output in the above function should works.

Comment: @JosephSible If I am using the debugger correctly, then I believe it is hanging at the last line of the function.

Comment: @JosephSible "Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.                                             
0x0000000000401d3e in PromoteTarget (headPtr=@0x7fffffffebc8: 0x615c80,                
    target=5) at llcpImp.cpp:284                                                       
                 current = current->link;"

Comment: Now that you've paused the program step it  until you see what the loop it's caught in. Once you know the loop, you probably have a good idea what variables have the wrong values and you can use the debugger to help find out where and how things really went wrong. Warning: The crash site is often nowhere near where the actual bug is.

Answer (score 0):

You can do both operations in a single traversal of the Linked List. During the traversal itself, every time a Node with `data` equal to `target` is encountered, shift this Node to the beginning of the Linked List and set the boolean variable `exists` to true. At the end of traversal, if `exists == false` then add a new Node to the end of the Linked List.

```
Node* createNode(int target)
{
    Node *newNodePtr = new Node;
    newNodePtr->data = target;
    newNodePtr->link = nullptr;
    return newNodePtr;
}

void PromoteTarget(Node*& headPtr, int target)
{
    if (headPtr == nullptr)
        headPtr = createNode(target);
    else
    {
        Node *prev, *curr;
        prev = headPtr;
        curr = headPtr->link;
        bool exists = false;
        while (curr != nullptr)
        {
            if (curr->data == target)
            {
                exists = true;
                prev->link = curr->link;
                curr->link = headPtr;
                headPtr = curr;
                curr = prev->link;
            }
            else
            {
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr->link;
            }
        }

        if (exists == false)
            prev->link = createNode(target);
    }
}
```